# How to use Static label and Buttons in Gui win32 Programming

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm learning win32 Programming. In order to better comprehend the concepts of the programming in win32 framework, So that I am going to write a simple calculator.  I design its view but now I want when a user click on a button, for example button 1, Its number shows on a static label. I used SetDlgItemText, But it doesn't work. I put the picture of the program in the following:

[image]

I have 12 button with IDs IDC_Button01 to IDC_Button12 and I have a static label element with IDC_Display ID. I put my code in the following section.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "resource.h"

#pragma comment(linker, \
  "\"/manifestdependency:type='Win32' "\
  "name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' "\
  "version='6.0.0.0' "\
  "processorArchitecture='*' "\
  "publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' "\
  "language='*'\"")
#pragma comment(lib, "ComCtl32.lib")

// Step 4: the Window Procedure
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
const char g_szClassName[] = "myWindowClass";

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hDlg;
    BOOL ret;
    MSG msg;

    hDlg = CreateDialogParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MainWindow), 0, DialogProc, 0);
    ShowWindow(hDlg, nCmdShow);

    // Step 3: The Message Loop
    while ((ret = GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) != 0) {
        if (ret == -1) /* error found */
            return -1;
        if (!IsDialogMessage(hDlg, &msg)) {
            TranslateMessage(&msg); /* translate virtual-key messages */
            DispatchMessage(&msg); /* send it to dialog procedure */
        }
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}

// Step 4: the Window Procedure

INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDCANCEL:
            SendMessage(hDlg, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
            return TRUE;
        case IDOK:
            MessageBox(hDlg, TEXT("Program will quit."), TEXT("Message"), MB_ICONQUESTION);
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return TRUE;
        }
        break;
    case IDC_BUTTON1:
        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_Display, TEXT("1"));
    case WM_CLOSE:
        if (MessageBox(hDlg, TEXT("Close the program?"), TEXT("Close"), MB_ICONQUESTION | MB_YESNO) == IDYES)
        {
            DestroyWindow(hDlg);
        }
        return TRUE;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: @MarcoA.: Uhm... the resource scripts were there before MFC was even planned. You'll need to read Petzold's *Programming Windows*, in case you haven't. Dialog templates (which the Resource Editor creates among other things) are a Windows API feature, not an MFC feature.

Comment: Please read [Button Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775941.aspx): *"Notifications from a button are sent as either [WM_COMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647591.aspx) or [WM_NOTIFY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775583.aspx) messages."* Buttons do not send their ID as a message. Also wise to insert a `break;` in case you don't want button presses to close your application.

Comment: @IInspectable I brought MFC as an example of something that uses dialog templates. It seemed to me OP wanted to create something from scratch. I'll remove the message in case it was misleading.

Comment: @MarcoA.: So? The dialog editor is the perfect tool here. It allows the dialog manager to create the controls for you, so you don't have to write hundreds of line of boilerplate code. The call to `CreateDialogParam` should be indication enough, that a dialog template from a resource should be used, and this part of the code apparently works as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource ID is not a valid [Windows message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381405(v=vs.85).aspx), the [WM_COMMAND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms647591(v=vs.85).aspx) is used to send a notification to a parent window

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND hDlg, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  ..
  case WM_COMMAND:
    switch (LOWORD(wParam))
    {
    case IDC_BUTTON1: {
      SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_Display, TEXT("1"));
      return TRUE;
    } break;
    break;
```

`wParam` is set to the control identifier.